# journalctl search case insensitive

Tags: systemd, journalctl

When I search in `journalctl` with `/` the search is case sensitive unless I switch to case insensitive with `-i` first.

How can I configure journalctl so that searches are case insensitive by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason journalctl does not use the `LESS` environment variable but uses `SYSTEMD_LESS`:

> ```
>   $SYSTEMD_LESS
>       Override the options passed to less (by default "FRSXMK").
> ```

Since less is already the default pager you can configure

```
export SYSTEMD_LESS=-i
```

or use the same options as less:

```
export SYSTEMD_LESS="$LESS"
```

Comment: I would add that to get the default `journalctl` paging experience *and* case-insensitive searching, one needs to also specify the default options as listed above. In other words, `SYSTEMD_LESS=-iFRSXMK`.

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
alias journalctli="SYSTEMD_PAGER='less -i' journalctl"
```

or add

```bsh
export SYSTEMD_PAGER="less -i"
```

to any of these files: `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/environment` or `/etc/profile.d/journalctl.sh`

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do you know why less does not use `export LESS="-i"` when I use it with `export SYSTEMD_PAGER=less`?

Comment: `less` is a separate utility and has its own environment parameters. They are not connected in any way - `systemd` can use any other pager, e.g. `more`.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 237, `journalctl` has the [`g, --grep=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/journalctl.html#-g) *filtering option*.

> Filter output to entries where the `MESSAGE=` field matches the specified regular expression. [...]
>
> **If the pattern is all lowercase, matching is case insensitive**. Otherwise, matching is case sensitive. This can be overridden with the [`--case-sensitive[=BOOLEAN]`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/journalctl.html#--case-sensitive=BOOLEAN) option [...].

The following example grep-matches all journald entries since boot which messages contain the string `efi`, *case-insensitive*, because the provided *needle* `efi` is all lowercase:

```
journalctl --boot --grep efi
```

In my sample run, this matched the following messages, among others:

```
efi: EFI v2.8 by INSYDE Corp.
efifb: probing for efifb
fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 3488.888 MHz
```